# Url actual y url origen php

Tags: php

¿Como puedo obtener con `php` la `url` actual donde se está ejecutando el script?

¿Es posible obtener cual es la `url` de origen si la hubiera?

Ejemplo:

Si la url es: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/76245/edit` como puedo obtenerla con `php`??

Comment: Deberias aportar algo de más información y el código (o la parte correspondiente al problema de él). Mirate [ask] y [mcve]

Comment: No es lo mismo, yo no tengo problemas con el .htaccess @Mariano

Comment: Es lo mismo para cualquier caso. Si lo que te interesa es obtener la URL tal cual se muestra en el navegador, como mostraste en tu ejemplo, esa es la forma, que no te fallaría independientemente de cómo o dónde se ejecute.

Comment: El comentario de @Mariano no es irrespetuoso ni abusivo, se genera solo al votar para cerrar. Evita hacer este tipo de reportes.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` que, tal y como indica en la **[documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php)**:

> Contiene la ruta del script actual. Esto es de utilidad para las páginas que necesiten apuntarse a si mismas. La constante **FILE** contiene la ruta absoluta y el nombre del archivo actual incluido.